# Formation of Saturn's Rings

Tags: solar-system

Assuming the rings of Saturn started out as a disorganized cloud of debris, what forces made these rings so thin and flat? Does frame dragging play a part in this?

Comment: Hi Bob. It's always [worth a quick search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=saturn+rings) to see if a question has been asked before. Actually that search finds lots of things about Saturn's rings that you might find interesting.